# Query to fetch data from two tables using order by and < operator

Tags: oracle

SQL gurus - I need some help

```
Table A ( number , name , subject , col 4 )
Table B ( number , name , subject , col 4 , col 5 etc )
```

For every row in Table A,  I want the following row from table B:

```
(a.name = b.name
a.subject = b.subject
b.number < a.number) order by desc and rownum = 1
```

Basically, the row in table B, whose number value is closet to the number value in table A.

```
Table A ( 3 rows )
20171208001735 xxx username1
20171208004123 yyy username1
20171209053231 xxx username2

Table B ( n rows )
20171209083227 yyy username2 
20171209083216 aaa username2 
20171209053142 xxx username2 <---- tag to row 3 from Table A 
20171209025647 yyy username1 
20171209002611 bbb username1 
20171209002609 ccc username1 
20171208002602 yyy username1 <---- tag to row 2 from table A 
20171209002315 ddd username1 
20171209002302 ggg username1 
20171208001523 xxx username1 <---- tag to row 1 from table A 
20171209001806 zzz username1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One approach here is to perform the join between the two tables using the conditions you mentioned, and then introduce `ROW_NUMBER` to find the single record of interest for each record in table A.  The criteria for the match, since the A number is strictly greater than the B number, is that we want the *highest* number from the B table.  So the ordering in `ROW_NUMBER` is given by the B number in descending order.

```
SELECT *     -- this can be replaced with an actual list of columns you want
FROM
(
    SELECT a.*, b.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.name, a.subject ORDER BY b.number DESC) rn
    FROM tableA a
    LEFT JOIN tableB b
        ON a.name = b.name AND
           a.subject = b.subject AND
           a.number > b.number
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1;
```

Comment: I tried something along the same lines and I got the following message

Comment: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 73 Column: 28

Comment: @Arun Typo `PARITION` instead of `PARTITION`.

Comment: Thx Tim - here is the challenge.  Table A has multiple entries for same name and subject; only the number column changes.  And I need the data from table B for each entry in table A

Comment: Yes I ran it -  I have 15 rows in table A; so I should get 15 line items from the above query.  I get only 5, which is the unique number of names in table A

Comment: @Arun Then perhaps doing a left join between the tables would make more sense?

Comment: I am getting the same results

Comment: You're going to have to make your question reproducible.  Can you add some sample data to your question?

Comment: @Arun Put this data into your question, formatted as text.

Comment: @ Tim -  tried couple of different way to add the data set to the long description, but the formatting is still off.    I can send you an email with data, if that 's ok

Comment: I have send you an email from arunsubbu@hotmail.com